# GTK+3: Passing colours from Python to CSS

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygi-aio

In the app I'm building, I have a variable with a hex colour code:

```
accentColour = "#0877df"
```

This value can be changed by the user.

Since I'm using GTK+3, I'm using a CSS file to style the widgets. How can I pass the accentColour variable to use as a colour in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Instead, I would put only the default color in your CSS file. Then make a CSS string in your code that overrides only the things that are affected by the color change, and add it in a separate CSS provider.

Comment: I don't think I've ever done inline CSS strings like that, how would I go about it? If it's a string, do I simply concatenate strings together?

Comment: Yes, you can load a string containing CSS code just as you can load a file containing CSS code: http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/CssProvider.html#Gtk.CssProvider.load_from_data